# Facebook Pixel load / response time very slow

Tags: facebook-pixel

I have implemented a Facebook pixel on my homepage and am annoyed by the long loading/response time of the pixel.
Website finish-time without pixel 0.8s - with pixel 2.5s (google developer console). I searched the internet for a long time without success - do you have any idea to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook pixel firing is dependent on the server and language platform. You have to reduced the extra calls and put the Facebook script in the header of the page.

Share your code if still you got the issue..

Comment: In almost every case, Facebook Pixel's load time is *not* dependent on the server. Unless the OP is using the Offline Conversions feature, which they did not mention, everything runs client-side. The suggestion of sharing the code/HTML is good, but belongs in a comment rather than an answer.